# Using an IF statement without repeating a long formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can `IF` check and return the result from a formula without using it a second time inside the cell?

I am talking about using something like this:

```
IF( LARGE(A2:A21) > 0, LARGE(A2:A21), "No Data Entered")
```

**This is an example/placeholder.**  My actual formula is a bit longer. I do not want to rewrite the formula (i.e. `LARGE()` ) within the `IF` function a second time.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: It is a good idea to use some helper cell(s)/column(s)/row(s) to simplify your formula :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way of which I can think would be to first put the `LARGE` formula into another cell, say `A1`, and then refer to that cell, e.g.

```
A1: =LARGE(A2:A21)

=IF(A1 > 0, A1, "No Data Entered")
```

This avoids having to repeat the possibly long code for the formula, but at the cost of using an intermediate column, which you might not want to do for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array form of LARGE() that will return an error if no value is greater than 0:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(A2:A21>0,A2:A21),1),"No Data Entered")
```

This would need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Scott, random question, did you get a goody package when you broke 100K?  I ask because when I broke 250K I got nothing, and they said they were switching providers (still haven't gotten anything) +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not even an email.

Comment: That's messed up.  I did get the email, but the line about the swagger package was missing (I did get swagger at 100K, 2+ years ago).

Comment: The formula I used was far more complicated so I couldn't use this solution. But thanks a lot.

Comment: I bet I could help you make it work. :) But I would need to see the full formula. @SumitMishra

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Dump!$B$2:$B$500,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(Dashboard!$H$3:H3,Dump!$B$2:$B$500),0)),"")`
here's the formula @ScottCraner. It is an array formula though. And I wanted to check if the final result is 0, then print a blank cell, else print the result.
The problem was solved by using extra cells, so no pressure. But I am really curious to see how else it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX`, Double-Division, and an `IfError`:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/MAX(0,COMPLICATED_FORMULA_HERE)),"No Data Entered")
```

If `COMPLICATED_FORMULA_HERE` is >0, then the `MAX` means that you calculate `1/(1/COMPLICATED_FORMULA_HERE)`, which is the same as `COMPLICATED_FORMULA_HERE` (because dividing by a fraction is the same as multiplying by its inverse - `1*(COMPLICATED_FORMULA_HERE/1)`)

If `COMPLICATED_FORMULA_HERE` is ≤0, then the `MAX` means that you calculate `1/(1/0)`, which is a `#DIV/0!` error.  The `IFERROR` then changes this into "No Data Entered"

(As I hope is obvious, `COMPLICATED_FORMULA_HERE` is a placeholder for whatever your actual formula is, much as you have used `LARGE(A2:A21)` - which is invalid, because `LARGE` requires 2 arguments)

Answer (score 2):

The `LET` formula can be used for this exact scenario.  You can define the formula as a variable and then within that same cell you can reference the variable in your formula.

### The `LET` formula format looks like this:

```
=LET(name,name_value,calculation)
```

### Your Example

Original formula:

```
=IF( LARGE(A2:A7,2) > 0, LARGE(A2:A7,2), "No Data Entered")
```

Here's how it would work using `LET` so that you don't have to repeat the formula:
[image: Screenshot of LET formula]

New formula:

```
=LET(runnerup,LARGE(A2:A7,2),IF(runnerup>0,runnerup,"No Data Entered"))
```

### Explanation

We create a variable and use the `LARGE` formula as the value of that variable.  We then write our `IF` statement using the variable name instead of rewriting the formula multiple times.

```
=LET(name,name_value,calculation)
```

Variable name:  `runnerup`

Variable value: `LARGE(A2:A7,2)`

Calculation:    `IF(runnerup>0,runnerup,"No Data Entered")`

Put together it looks like this:

```
=LET(runnerup,LARGE(A2:A7,2),IF(runnerup>0,runnerup,"No Data Entered"))
```

This `LET` function can be used in any Excel formula, and is very useful for shortening long formulas that have repetition.

---

### Optional: Extra complexity

If you want to you can get extra complicated by naming multiple variables.

```
=LET(name,name_value,name2,name_value2,calculation)
```